# Change a file's x-y position on windows desktop with Python

Tags: python, windows, powershell, command-line

I want to try and change the x-y position of a file on desktop using a python script. Using powershell or cmd prompt to do it would also be fine.
To clarify, I'm not trying to change the directory, but instead the actual x-y location on the desktop.

I have looked everywhere on the internet and can't find anything that says something about how to do this, even just in powershell or command prompt

Comment: You would need this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-setitemposition32?redirectedfrom=MSDN and also see this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505766/how-do-i-move-windows-desktop-icons-using-python-2-7   ...what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, because I had no clue where to start. I'll try using those and get started. Thank you!